# CoreData: NSPredicate filter by date

Tags: swift, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a dataset which contains the following date `6/14, 6/15, 6/16, 6/17 and 6/18`

I have two predicates

```
let today = NSDate() 
NSPredicate(format: "checked == %@ AND dateTime >= %@", NSNumber(bool: false), today)
NSPredicate(format: "checked == %@ AND dateTime < %@", NSNumber(bool: false), today)
```

let say today is `6/16` so according to the first predicate, fetchRequest should pick only `6/16, 6/17 and 6/18` and for second predicate, fetchRequest should only pick `6/14 and 6/15`.

But the problem is first predicate pick all the rows and second one return blank.

**DataModel**

[image: Data Model]

**conversion code**

[image]

Any idea what's going wrong here.

Comment: Did you really saved the dates as `NSDate` (and not as `NSString`)?

Comment: Attribute type is `Date` and during save I convert it to `NSTimeInterval`

Comment: show the model and that conversion code

Comment: Try `"... AND dateTime >= %f", NSNumber(bool:false), today.timeIntervalSince1970`, or `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`, according to your case.

Comment: It crash with `-[__NSCFNumber timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognised selector`

Comment: `today` is a `NSDate` or a `NSNumber` object?

Comment: `today` is `NSDate` but when I used `today.timeIntervalSince1970` it's become `double` then it crash.

Comment: I think that the issue is with `dateTime`, not `today`. `dateTime = NSDate(dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:Double(activityInfo["eventDateTime"] as! String))` or something like that.

Comment: @Larme thanks bro. it's work fine now.

Comment: Then, I guess that the issue was when you were saving the `dateTime`. If that's so, you can use your former predicate (with `%@` as placeholder, and just `today` as argument).

Comment: Yes. problem were in saving the `dateTime`. Would you like to post an answer?. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model you set the `dateTime` property as a `Date` object, but you saved it as a `double`.

So you have to do:

```
dateTime = NSDate(dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:Double(activityInfo["eventDateTime‌​"] as! String))
```

Note, I don't speak Swift, so I don't know if this code could be shorter, but you get the idea.